# Creating tables with CREATE TASK and common table expressions in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I am trying to use Snowflake's [CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task) function and I want to combine it using [CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#create-table-as-select-also-referred-to-as-ctas)

When I do something like

```sql
CREATE TASK "taskname" SCHEDULE = USING CRON '03 19 * * *' AS (

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE X.Y.Z AS (
with query_1 as (...),
query_2 as (...),
...
select * from result)
)
```

I get a generic error message like

```
SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'CREATE'.
syntax error line 4 at position 15 unexpected 'column_x'.
```

How can I schedule tasks similar to this?

My goal is to schedule a task to create a table using [CTAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas) statement with [CTE](https://www.atlassian.com/data/sql/using-common-table-expressions)s

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the actual SQL statement you are running rather than a version of it. As the error message indicates there's a syntax error we'd need to be able to see the full statement (both the CREATE and the SELECT parts) in order to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for task creation is like below, and also need to update create table statement,

table creation(no brackets after AS):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE X.Y.Z AS
with query_1 as (...),
query_2 as (...),
...
select * from result
```

task:

```
create task taskname
SCHEDULE = USING CRON '03 19 * * *'
AS
BEGIN
    <sql statements>
END;


CREATE TASK "taskname"
AS 
BEGIN
  CREATE or replace TABLE xyz AS 
    with query_1 as (select * from test),
    query_2 as (select * from test)
    
    select * from query_2;
END;
```